# Android Studio wont debug my app in my phone

Tags: android, debugging, keystore

I have very big difficulties of understanding what might be an issue, why android studio wont debug my app.
I developed it, wanted to do release.apk from the file and now i am in front of problem that app crashes and does not give me any error at all.

Last thing i did was deleting debug.keystore from .android folder
Also i generated signed APK.
One thing to notice that my app is using google play services. Maybe that might be an issue why it wont work correctly. 
Also my google_maps_api.xml is in /debug and /release folders.

I reseted my phone to factory settings,
Allowed to put developer mode again and set usb debugging enabled.

I deleted all breakpoints and put only one to line.
Nothing seems to work.

Also here is the error when i want to install my application for the second time:[image]

Help me!
I need to finish my project so i can put it in google play store!

Comment: You checked the logcat?

Comment: Gradle throws an error now :     Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: /data/app/vmdl26111935.tmp/1_slice__ signatures are inconsistent

Comment: The best suitable option is to try to do this ./gradlew assembleDebug( for Mac) and gradlew assembleDebug in (Window) in you CMD. It will give you a clear picture of what wrong is happening